# Java String type

Tags: java, memory-management, value-type, reference-type

I have this Java code:

```
String x = "abcgrfdhdrhfhtjfhtgdrfdjrtkkytjgykjgrthfd";
String y = "abcgrfdhdrhfhtjfhtgdrfdjrtkkytjgykjgrthfd";
System.out.println(x == y);
```

It prints out: true

How is this possible? Isn't String just a pointer to the first byte (character) of the string itself? Why does it act like a primitive type?

Comment: If you want to create a new instance, I think you need to do `new String(x)`.

Comment: Look at the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Give a look to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/3625883

Comment: It is a potential duplicate, but it's definitely not a duplicate of the one it was closed as a dupe of so have re-opened it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

S4 and S3 are `String` literals while S1 and S2 are `String` Objects.

```
String s1="java";//literal
String s2=new String("java");//Object
```

As `==` is used for checking whether two `Strings` are the same Object or not.Means referencing the same memory location or not.

Comment: To sum up: s3 and s4 are created with `new String(...)` while s1 and s2 are created like `String a = "aaa"`. Is that it?

Comment: @HugoSousa it's the other way around actually

Comment: @TimB Yep, messed up there.

Answer (score 0):

```
== operator check if the two references point to the same object or not.
```

Here both `x` and `y` pointing same value in `Heap`

Answer (score 0):

It prints out: true
**How is this possible?**

```
String x = "abcgrfdhdrhfhtjfhtgdrfdjrtkkytjgykjgrthfd"; 
// one String object created on the String pool.
String y = "abcgrfdhdrhfhtjfhtgdrfdjrtkkytjgykjgrthfd"; 
// y is a reference which points to the same object created abovr on the String pool.
So,
System.out.println(x == y); // true
```

**Isn't String just a pointer to the first byte (character) of the string itself? Why does it act like a primitive type?**

> Well, yes. String Objects are indeed backed by a character array. But
>   that has nothing to do with equality

Answer (score 0):

As you know Java == compares the references, it asks whether two objects are actually the same object, not just having the same value.

```
String x = "abcgrfdhdrhfhtjfhtgdrfdjrtkkytjgykjgrthfd";
String y = "abcgrfdhdrhfhtjfhtgdrfdjrtkkytjgykjgrthfd";
System.out.println(x == y);
```

In this case you have assigned x and y to point to the exact same String. Internally the Java compiler has noticed that both x and y are being given the same value, so to save space it has created only one String object - and then both x and y point to that object.

This is why x == y..

If you changed one or the other (or both) to:

```
String x = new String("abcgrfdhdrhfhtjfhtgdrfdjrtkkytjgykjgrthfd");
```

Then you would get the result `false`.